# Empty ListView layout not displayed in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I got a fragment with a `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layoutDirection="rtl" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPlaces"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

 <ViewStub
     android:id="@android:id/empty"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout="@layout/empty_list_layout" />
```

and the `empty_list_layout`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/no_result_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:text="@string/empty_list"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

I see the button in the middle of the Eclipse's graphical layout for `empty_list_layout` but when the list is empty, the layout is displayed at the top of the screen. Why is it not in the middle like the layout tell it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your parent view is `LinearLayout` with orientation as vertical and your empty `ViewStub` has height as `wrap_content`. So LinearLayout starts drawing its child from top to bottom.

You want to use `RelativeLayout` as parent.

Comment: Why doesn't it also work if I change the ViewStub's height to match parent? with its gravity and the other layout shouldnt it work?

Comment: Actually, `gravity` is used for its internal childs, the property you want to use is `layout_gravity` it'll effect the placement of gravity in its parent.

Comment: and as you can see from the xml:  android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: It won't affect until the parent layout supports it. LinearLayout doesn't fully supports it. Use RelativeLayout.